# List conversation between 2 users in the correct order

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I want to create a chat system on which i could list all the chats between specific 2 persons

I have 2 tables `users` and `chats`

my chats table have 3 columns - `user_id`, `friend_id` and `chat`

my `User.php` model file is like this

```
public function chats() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chat');
}
```

For eg:

I want to list all the chat between user 1 and 3 without changing the order of the conversation
I can simply do it by doing `$chats = Auth::user()->chats->where('friend_id', '=', $id);` but this will only give the authenticated (which is user 1 or 3) users chats. But I want the conversation between both of them.

So I have found an alternate way to do that by

```
$first = Chat::all()->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('friend_id', '=', $id);
$second = Chat::all()->where('user_id', '=', $id)->where('friend_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
$chats = $first->merge($second);
```

But this way has some problems. This will not get the chats in the correct order. I think it is impossible to order it correctly.

**So my question is how can I list the conversation between two persons in the correct order easily?**
If you want more details about my problem you can just ask.

Comment: There's no ordering mechanism in your tables. In relational data by default order is not guaranteed because it should not matter. If you want order to matter then you need to add a column to indicate order (e.g. datetime?).

Comment: @apokryfos I understood you. But is there any other way to do this by using laravel eloquent or something simpler other than packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it in one query with parameter grouping, rather than executing two separate queries and then merging them.

```
Chat::where(function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
          ->where('friend_id', '=', $id);
})->orWhere(function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $id)
          ->where('friend_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```

This *might* also return your results in the correct order, just because without any sort criteria specified, databases will often return rows in the order they were inserted. However, without adding something to your chat table to sort by, (either a timestamp or an autoincrement id), there's no way to guarantee it.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$first = Chat::all()->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
         ->where('friend_id', '=', $id)->get();
$second = Chat::all()->where('user_id', '=', $id)
          ->where('friend_id', '=', Auth::user()
          ->id)->get();
$chats = $first->merge($second)
         ->sortBy('created_at');//created_at is timing added change if other
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any laravel recommended method for this kind of chat application or is there any other way I can do it by using Laravel eloquent?

Comment: You can just store all chat message in one table to make it all easy.

Comment: @user2486 pointed it, `created_at` is exactly the "Laravel way", if you care about it. Just configure your model in consequence (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not do `all()` before filtering. This is bad because fetches all the table data and then does the filtering in PHP.

You should consider doing this:

In your migration:

```
Schema::create("chat", function (Blueprint $table) {
    //Other creation lines
    $table->timestamps();
})
```

Then in your chat model:

```
public function scopeInvolvingUsers($query, $userId,$friendId) {
     return $query->where([ ["user_id",$userId],["friend_id",$friendId] ])
                  ->orWhere([ ["user_id",$friendId],["friend_id",$userId] ]);
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
$chats = Chat::involvingUsers(\Auth::id(),$otherId)->latest()->get();
```

Note that `latest` or `earliest` requires the `timestamps` to be present on the table.

Answer (score 1):

I will add timestamps in chat table which will ensure the order.
To add timestamp into chat table just add

```
$table->timestamps();
```

and the you can select the chat related to the user and sort it by created_at.
In laravel 5.3+ use

```
Chats::where(['user_id', '=', Auth::id()], ['friend_id', '=', $id])->orWhere(['user_id', '=', $id], ['friend_id', '=', Auth::id()])->sortBy('created_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Chat::whereIn('user_id', [$id, Auth->user()->id])
->whereIn('friend_id', [$id, Auth->user()->id])->get();
```